# Query for aggregation of uptime of multiple apps with PromQL

Tags: grafana, prometheus

With PromQL, I am trying to query the uptime of multiple apps and visualise it with Grafana.

What I want is to have the "and" (I don't know if this is the right term) of the uptime of two applications, so it should only return 1 for any given point in time if **all** given apps in the query are up, else 0. In the end, I want to have one value, that shows me the average uptime of the last 30 days

This gives me what I want for one app (I need `clamp_max` and `> 0`, but this is not so important here).

```
avg_over_time((max by (job)(clamp_max(up{space="$space",job="job1"},1)) )[30d:5m]) > 0
```

How can I combine two of these queries, so I can get the desired result? I have consulted the PromQL docu, but haven't found the solution yet.

Answer (score 1):

The PromQL to indicate if all applications are up at any point in time can be computed by  testing when the sum of up target are equal to the number of target (filter and aggregation ommited):

```
count(up) == bool sum(up)
```

The `== bool` will yield a scalar [that is either 0 (false) or 1 (true), depending on the comparison result](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#comparison-binary-operators).

Then you can compute the average as you have indicated:

```
avg_over_time((count(up) == bool sum(up))[30d:5m])
```

With filtering, the expression becomes

```
avg_over_time((count(up{job=~"job[12]"}) == bool sum(up{job=~"job[12]"}))[30d:5m])
```

Comment: The question is: How can I combine this query, so I can specify job1 and job2 for example? I don't want all jobs.

Comment: You can filter the metrics with the `{tag=~"regex notation"}`, let me update the answer